# Change Associated list for a workflow

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to change the list association of a current workflow to work with another list? if so, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 5):

If the workflow is developed:

- using Visual Studio
- as a Reusable workflow in SharePoint designer
- in a 3rd party workflow product

then you can associate it with a new list.

If it's a SharePoint designer list workflow, then it's not supported, but you can find hacks like [Walkthrough: How to move or copy a SharePoint Designer 2010 List Workflow to another list on the same site or another site.](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/walkthrough-how-to-move-or-copy-a-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow-to-another-list-on-the-same-site-or-another-site/)